# Calculate the cumulative in Python

Tags: python

How to code the following cumulative in Python

If I have

```
  x=1, y=2
  cum1=x*y+0=2
  cum2=x*y+cum1=4
  cum3=x*y +cum2=6
```

And so on

Comment: You seem to be describing `cum[n] = n*x*y` in a roundabout way. But I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: What issues are you currently having implementing this?

Comment: @Onfe gave me a nice answer, however, I want to stop the calculation of the cum when it achieve a certain value. Instead of having 10 in the range, I will have a big cum value. And once the cum is => than teh cum value it will stop the cum calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to repeat the same operation multiple times, therefore you can use a loop that holds on to the previous value.

```
x = 1
y = 2
previous = 0

for i in range(0, 10):
    new = x*y + previous
    print(new)
    previous = new

# output: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 etc..
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to stop the calculation of the cum when it achieve a certain value. Instead of having 10 in the range, I will have a big cum value. And once the cum is => than the cum value it will stop the cum calculation

Comment: There should be an if statement

Comment: @Rory feel free to adjust the answer to more accurately represent your use-case, I was just answering the question posed.